# Do properties in F# classes double memory used in private fields?

Tags: class, memory, f#

F# classes have the nice property that arguments automatically become immutable private fields. If I want to make one such field available externally I can create a property, like `I` in the code below:

```
type MyClass (i: int list) =
    member this.I with get() = i
    member this.foo x = i.Head + x

let mc = MyClass [0..10]
mc.foo 10 // 10
mc.I // [0; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10]
```

Does `I` in the code above double the amount of memory used for `i` or is it just a function that returns the value of `i`?

(Of course this is only relevant if the argument uses a lot of memory, which is not the case in the example above)

Answer (score 6):

No: `i` gets stored as a private field inside of `MyClass`; `MyClass.I` is a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/properties) whose `get` function returns the value of said field.

`list<'T>` is a reference type, so persisting it inside of the class is effectively a shallow copy and will not duplicate the data inside of the list.